# C# Access Login form with saving ID

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, authentication

I need to create login form with saving ID of logged in user. I have already working login form. Can you help and tell me, where I should change the code to save my ID depending on the entered Username and Password?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Project\Database.mdb");
    OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select Count(*) From Datatable where Username ='" + textBox1.Text + "' and Password ='" + textBox2.Text + "'", con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
    {
        this.Hide();
        Form1 ss = new Form1();
        ss.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect name or password");
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll first need to retrieve the ID, not just SELECT COUNT. Also, use parameters - Don't build up your SQL string like that, it's wide open for SQL injection attack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing as a global variable in C#.
If you want to store ID on log in I recommend you to create something like this:

```
public static class Globals
{
    public static String ID; // Modifiable in Code
}
```

So you could use this property called `ID` wherever you want in your code, for example:

```
 if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
 {
        Globals.ID = "YOUR ID";

        this.Hide();
        Form1 ss = new Form1();
        ss.Show();
 }
```

And once you set this Globals.ID to your value, that will be available to your wherever in your code (provided you are working on the same namespace).

Comment: @BogdanFomin please vote up if this answer was helpful to you :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have enough rep for now. But I hope I'll get it soon so I can vote for your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there's no such thing as a global variable in C#.
And Roxy'Pro's answer is perfect but for a little bit of security i would recommend

```
 //this will create a variable that belongs to no class
 private static string id;

 //This will create a get property for the variable "id"
 public static string ID{get{return id;}}

 if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
 {
        id = "YOUR ID";

        this.Hide();
        Form1 ss = new Form1();
        ss.Show();
 }
```

And once you set this id to your value, you can retrieve it anywhere via the property created using the "className.PropertyName" . This will make sure ones you set the 'id', you want accidentally change the value anywhere in your code.